# getting wrong position on first load

Tags: jquery, html

Hi my code is only breaking on first load for some reason. I am getting wrong value for left variable which is creating issue. once I click on one of the tabs everything starts working fine even on refresh. Now if i clear cache and run from beginning same issue starts again.

please someone help me solve the problem:

check the below code.

I tried putting on on load event. still didn't work

```
<section class="section product_category_landing">
    <div class="grid-container tabbed_nav_wrap">
        <div class="tabbed_nav grid-100">
            <a href="javascript:" id="tab_overview" rel="tab_1">Overview</a>
            <a href="javascript:" id="tab_video_creative_tools" rel="tab_2">Video Creative Tools</a>
            <a href="javascript:" id="tab_media_management" rel="tab_3">Media Management</a>
            <a href="javascript:" id="tab_storage_and_servers" rel="tab_4">Storage & Servers</a>
            <a href="javascript:" id="tab_support_and_services" rel="tab_5">Support & Services</a>
            <div class="nav_item_bg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-container more-col-spacing">
        <div id="tab_1" class="tabbed_container">
            <div class="grid-100">
                <h2><a href="">Avid Motion Graphics</a></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab_2" class="tabbed_container">
            <div class="grid-100">
                <h2><a href="">New Section Here</a></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">         
    $(function(){
    // Tabbed Containers
    $('.tabbed_nav a').on('click', function(e) {
        console.log("clicked");
        var $container = $('.tabbed_container#' + $(e.target).attr('rel')),
                $hover = $('.nav_item_bg'),
                tab_name = e.target.id.replace('tab_', '');
                console.log(tab_name);

        $('.tabbed_container:visible').hide();
        $container.show();
        $('.tabbed_nav a.current').removeClass('current');
        $(e.target).addClass('current');

        document.location.replace('#' + tab_name);

        if($hover.is(':hidden')) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $hover.show();
            }, 1);
        }
                    //alert("if this is uncommented it works.");
        var width = $(e.target).outerWidth(),
                left = $(e.target).position().left;//I am getting wrong left position on first load for some reason.

        $hover.css({
            width: width,
            left: left
        });

    });


    // Tabbed Nav Hash in URL
    var hash = document.location.hash.replace('#', '');

    setTimeout(function() {
        if(hash !== '') {
            hash = '#tab_' + hash;
            $(hash).click();
        } else {
            if($('.tabbed_nav').length > -1) {
                $('.tabbed_nav a:first').click();
            }
        }
    }, 150);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like you should use onhashchange event instead of this killer joy timeout

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript"> ` use just `<script>` what else could it be? :)

Answer (score -1):

i would strongly suggest putting your code in a function that executes once the page is loaded:

```
document.onload =afterPageLoad;
function afterPageLoad(){
    //put your code here
}
```

or this one if you dont have asynchronous elements:

```
$(function(){
    //put your code here

});
```

that way you are making sure all elements have loaded already before you take sizes and measurements

EDIT:

also i see that you use `position().left`,  are you sure you need position? because position takes the position relative to parent element.

try using `.offset().left` instead, and see if it helps

Comment: For async elements as image, better would be to use window onload event, especially to get right size of elements

Comment: @Banana no it is not, it is equivalent to DOMContentLoaded which is fired before any async elements has been loaded (if not cached)

Comment: window.load also didn't work. what worked was when i put an alert before i calculate the left value. it works

Comment: @susheel its because your alert probably created some delay which allowed the page to load. and its document.onload, not window